# MongoDB: Lookup - Collections with Same Fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've two collections `Users` and `Notes`. Both collections contain an `id` property and the `Notes` collection has an `userid` that is the id of some user on the `Users` collection.

Now, I'm trying to aggregate (join) some user information into `Notes`:

```js
db.getCollection("Notes").aggregate(
{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "Users",
        "let": {
            "idForeignField": "$id"
        },
        "pipeline": [
                            {
            "$match": {
                "$expr": {
                    "$and": [{
                        "$eq": ["$userid", "$$idForeignField"]
                    }]
                }
            }
                            }
        ],
        "as": "Users#joined"
    }
}
);
```

What I get in a empty `Users#joined` array. Why? Shouldn't my query work? Is the problem caused by the fact that both collections have an `id` property? If yes how can I tell `let` and `match` what is the right collection?

**Update**: alternatively a simpler query works just fine:

```js
db.getCollection("Notes").aggregate(
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: "Users",
       localField: "userid",
       foreignField: "id",
       as: "Users#joined"
     }
}
);
```

However I would like to do it with `let` and a pipeline in order to add more `match` conditions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `let` variable must be `userid`

```
db.getCollection("Notes").aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "Users",
    "let": { "ifForeignField": "$userid" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$and": [{ "$eq": ["$id", "$$ifForeignField"] }] }}}
    ],
    "as": "Users#joined"
  }}
])
```